# Higher rep deductions for big rep downvoters

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes, high-rep-users

Long time lurker of Stack Overflow and big fan. I can't count how many times it has gotten me out of a programming pinch. I'm honestly not too concerned about rep, I try to gain rep so that when I do have the big and nasty programming question, I can bounty it up and get a good answer. But I have been on this site for years and seen that higher rep comes attached with a higher rate of answer acceptance, answer up-votes and --in some cases-- a larger percentage of down-votes from the higher rep peeps. God-complex anyone?

That being said, should there be a scaling system for higher rep'd people to have larger deductions? Is this feature currently installed and I am blissfully ignorant? Or am I simply a lowly <1k rep'd user with a furrowed brow rapidly hitting the refresh button on favorite tags while fighting the system?

Comment: within seconds, it gets downvoted. lol

Comment: It got downvoted because someone disagreed with it

Comment: Not a problem, that's why I asked. It is a discussion question after all. I would appreciate an opinion on it though.

Comment: Downvoting a question cost 0 rep (free). Downvoting an answer cost 1 reputation point. No matter if you have 125 (minimum required to downvote) or 1,000,000 reputation points. That's how it is, and honestly not sure what you want to discuss here?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Cheers @Rich, so was it just a support question, or is there anything you want to discuss?

Comment: I would like further opinions on this as I have noticed that some higher repped users do exploit there rep to downvote other answers. But if this is just me and a non-useful question then by all means close it.

Comment: I don't really think it is just you, sure it happens, but I wouldn't say it is the norm.

Comment: Whether the cost of downvoting should scale up with rep, it seems. I'm gonna say no, personally. I don't see what it would achieve beyond confusion; these folks generally aren't worried about losing rep (I assume), and I disagree with discouraging the relatively more experienced users from voting.

Comment: `higher repped users do exploit there rep to downvote other answers` can you point to specific examples of this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have come unprepared. My apologies for this.

Comment: Can you explain why did you rollback the edit? Also, "hi" "thanks" are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/187824). And aren't you talking about the high reputation users?

Comment: You edited it to remove the serial voting tag. Then edited my question to your preferences. I disagreed with your preferences but removed the serial voting, as it was accurately inappropriate. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Did you read my comment? I didn't edit to my preferences. I removed "thanks" because it is not encouraged. Also you removed [high-rep-users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-rep-users) tag.

Comment: Honestly dude, I'm having to much fun with my friends this friday night to care if or if not you are disturbed by my keeping a smiley face and "thanks". Edit away! No more rollbacks tonight. Promise.

Comment: I personally downvote more now simply because I feel more comfortable on the site and I know its mechanism better than when I had lower rep. Not sure why you would call it exploiting though. I would call it moderating.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> higher rep comes attached with a higher rate of answer acceptance, answer up-votes

This may be true but the way people decide to vote/accept is up to that person. Does this mean that the answers shouldn't be upvoted/accepted? In most cases, I would venture to say that this is because the higher rep people articulate their answers better with better explanations, examples, and links. They also will go the extra mile often times to correct other things that are wrong. And, yes, there are obviously times where it probably happens because they have a lot of rep and people respect them...not much we can do there.

> a larger percentage of down-votes from the higher rep peeps. God-complex anyone?

God-complex? Not usually. More often than not it is because those higher rep "peeps" have been around longer and know how to better use the flags, downvotes, and other tools they have earned. I recently have spent more time on meta and have learned this so I can use my flags a little more sparingly and downvotes more liberally, when called for.

So, to answer your question,

> should there be a scaling system for higher rep'd people to have larger deductions?

I don't think so. We should punish people with higher rep for using the site more wisely and trying to keep it cleaner? Seems pretty counter-productive if you ask me...and you did.

Comment: Thank you very much. Good information here.

Comment: You're welcome. But I won't be offended if you wait longer if everything wasn't addressed clearly. There are a lot of folks on here that give very good,clear answers.

Comment: And I'm not saying I wouldn't appreciate their answers if they were included. I knew going into this question it would be down voted quickly. Rep lost -gasp- no way! But when a user has a question, regardless of positive or negative rep, I feel it should be discussed. This was as adequate of an answer as I was seeking. Regardless of outcome. I really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rich you get downvotes here because it appears you want downvotes to cost more as reputation goes up, and people strongly disagree with this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand and accept the repercussions of my actions. I wanted to discuss this with the meta.stackoverflow community, so I brought it to light.

Comment: Very brave, @Rich - kudos!

Comment: I don't think I can be counted as a high rep user but I wouldn't mind paying more rep for down voting answers. Most of those I down vote get deleted anyway and I get my rep back.